# mysql server unhandled exception error after installation version 8.0

Tags: mysql-workbench

Just installed mysql and ran into this error. Unhandeled exception has occured in your application.

See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************

```
'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MySql.Installer.Plugins.Server.ServerConfigurationController.ValidateServerFilesHaveRecommendedPermissions()
      at MySql.Installer.Plugins.Server.ServerConfigurationController.SetPages()
       at MySql.Installer.Wizards.ConfigWizard.ConfigWizard.ShowWizard(Package package, MainForm     parentMainForm, ConfigurationType configurationType)
       at MySql.Installer.Core.Controls.MyListView.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
         at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WmReflectNotify(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.ListView.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)'
```

Uninstalled and reinstalled but that did not help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.